# XMLStreamReader - What happens at the end of the file?

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

When traversing an XML document like so

```
while(streamReader.hasNext()){
    streamReader.next();
    if(streamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT){
        System.out.println(streamReader.getLocalName());
    }
}
```

Do I need to create a new streamReader if I need to traverse the XML document again, like so?

```
   XMLStreamReader streamReader =
        factory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
```

I don't see a method like 'reset()' to move the cursor back to the start of the XML file

Comment: Are there any alternative XML-stream readers that do have additional support for 'previous' and/or 'reset' functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should create a new reader at that point.

If you need to traverse the document multiple times, do you definitely want to parse it in a streaming fashion in the first place, rather than loading it into a DOM of some description?

Comment: No, because in the future the XML file could get quite large so for safety, I'm sticking with a StAX parser. Parsing it as a DOM might take too much memory. Thanks for the answer.